# Map object properties to array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, dictionary, properties

Is this possible to do in `C#`?

I have *POCO* object here is definition:

```
public class Human
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Age{get;set;}
    public int Weight{get;set;}
}
```

I would like to map properties of object `Human` to string array.

Something like this:

```
Human hObj = new Human{Name="Xi",Age=16,Weight=50};
```

Or I can have `List<Human>`:

```
string [] props = new string [COUNT OF hObj PROPERTIES];

foreach(var prop in hObj PROPERTIES)
{
    props["NAME OF PROPERTIES"] = hObj PROPERTIES VALUE    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this:

```
var props = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach(var prop in hObj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);)
{
    props.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(hObj, null));
}
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332493%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for info on GetProperties and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) for PropertyInfo

Comment: As noted, Reflection will get you the desired result.  Please keep in mind that Reflection isn't very efficient and will result in a noticeable performance hit if your lists get very big.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get an object's properties and values:

```
var properties = typeof(Human).GetProperties();

IList<KeyValuePair<string, object>> propertyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
{
    propertyValues.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(oneHuman));
}
```